# What's the average size of a smart contract on Ethereum?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

what's the average size of a smart contract on Ethereum ?
I already searched for it on google , twitter , reddit , duckduckgo but everything in vain

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a programming question (just as "what's the average size of a Python program on github" would not be a programming question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximal size allowed by the network is 24576 (hex 0x6000) bytes, as per the [EIP-170](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-170). An empty contract compiled with the latest compiler version results in 92 bytes. So the average is somewhere between those numbers.

How to calculate the average contract size:

1. Loop through all existing blocks, get their transaction hashes
2. Loop through all transaction hashes and query the respective transaction receipts ([docs](https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API#%20eth_gettransactionreceipt))
3. You're interested only in those that contain non-empty `contractAddress` field, meaning these transactions were contract deployments
4. Each of the `contractAddress` fields point to a contract address
5. Query the `eth_getCode` method ([docs](https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API#%20eth_getcode)) for each of these addresses, which returns the contract binary. Add the binary length to your calculation, and finally divide by the number of results.

Mind that some contracts might have been selfdestruct, so they'll return 0 size even though they have been previously deployed. Depending on your method, you may or may not want to include the selfdestruct contracts in your calculation, or possibly query their (non-zero) size at the block of their creation.